# Unauthorized to view the page when <g:link> action call to controller method

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying this in a grails application:

1. Controller-> say Books
2. list -> say Books list page

I created a new method in controller-->booksShow(),
When I try to call this method in
`<g:link action="booksShow" params="${booksinstance}">Books</g:link>`

I am getting "Unauthorized to access this page" filter is redirecting it to display this.

My question is do I need to add/register that new method in any property files to give permission to call that method?? 
&
how to pass the books instance as param in the  param field
kindly help me on this 
Thanks

Comment: what says `Unauthorized to access this page` springSecurity ? you need to check logs to find out what is causing the issue - question doesn't delve into security

Comment: thanks for the reply vahid, I think I have to configure the permission to access that method.